# how can i store multiple markers in database using rails in same field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new on ruby. I want to know that how can I store multiple markers in database using google maps. I want to store values of longitude and latitude in single attributes in database.

This is my controller code for storing single values in database from markers

```
@product.latitude = params[:product]['latitude']   
@product.longitude = params[:product]['longitude']
```

This is my javascript for map

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (evt) {
  var location =  evt.latLng
  placeMarker(location);
  $("#product_latitude").val(location.lat());
  $("#product_longitude").val(location.lng());
});
```

Comment: please share your code, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask...welcome to SO

Comment: @Jadeye I have updated my question can you please review it.

Comment: did you google this??? plenty of information out there...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28484487/ruby-on-rails-google-maps-api-displaying-multiple-markers AND http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42234198/ruby-on-rails-geocoder-objects-as-google-map-marker-array

Comment: You can push each marker into an array and then serialize them to be stored in DB

Comment: @Jadeye this is to show markers which are already created in database i want the user to pin multiple markers while creating  a post. And i want that markers to be stored in database.

Comment: @DamianSimonPeter Can you please give me a reference that how can i do that. i am new to ruby

Comment: @yawar take a look at this SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21312278/storing-arrays-in-database-json-vs-serialized-array
It clearly explains how to do it the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the click event happens you will send a ajax request to Controller where you can use reverse geo code and can convert these lat,lng into address and can save it . on every click new pin will be added and ajax request will called to server